# Drupal display php in body

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I've made a page "test" and I want to place this code in the body

$name=db_result(db_query('SELECT NOW( )');
   print $name;

even though the input type is PHP it will not show up.

I tried a peice of example code I found and it worked fine

```
Hello
 <p>Welcome!</p>
    Today's date is: 
  <?php
 echo date('m/d/Y');
  ?>
```

What I ultimately want to accomplish is for all my php code to be able to display within the content body of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your php code is missing a closing paren; try it with the same number of closing parentheses as opening (3):

`$name=db_result(db_query('SELECT NOW( )')); print $name;`